# How to get code completion to work for PHP in Netbeans?

Tags: php, frameworks, netbeans, code-completion

How to get code completion to work for PHP in Netbeans 6.9.1?
I want Netbeans to suggest native PHP functions.

[image]

#### EDIT:

The auto complete only works for reserved vars and reserved keywords but not for native functions.  Looking at the example above, it should suggest e.g str_replace, strlen, etc...that doesnt happen even after CTRL + SPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure you have enabled the PHP plugin, that should do the trick. BTW autocomplete might not work while NetBeans is checking for project changes though...

Comment: Am using the PHP version of Netveans i assume the PHP plug-in is enabled already right?

Comment: It should be. Did you create a new PHP project? And does the file have a PHP extension (.php/.phtml)? I always limit the number of open projects to the minimum to keep the time NB uses for scanning as low as possible.

Comment: BTW You could also try installing the [ScanOnDemand](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ScanOnDemand) plugin to stop NB from scanning for changes on startup (you can always do this check manually if needed using Source -> Scan for external changes). When I tried it, it seemed to screw up my NetBeans installation, so make sure you try it on a clean, non-critical installation to see if it works for you...

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me from time to time when I used NetBeans. I used the CTRL+SPACE shortcut to invoke the code completion window.

UPDATE:
If you're interested, you can also use VIM, which has a code completion feature for php as well.

Assuming you have VIM 7 (Full version) installed, add the following to your .vimrc file:

```
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
```

To use the code completion window, simply use CTRL+X CTRL+O

Comment: @OV Web Solutions thanks for the suggestion, but CTRL + SPACE shows no suggestions.

Comment: @Babiker I experienced the same thing several times. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't. Especially if it was scanning projects, which for me, was the deal breaker.  The constant scanning kept me down, and was affecting my production time.  I provided lots of data to the NetBeans support team, but in the end, I returned to VIM.  Let me know if you're interested in VIM. I'll gladly post an update on how you can use code completion in VIM. Best

Comment: @Babiker Alternatively, you can try NetBeans 7.0 Beta - scanning is improved, not sure about code completion though.  The development roadmap shows a stable version will be available in March 2011: http://netbeans.org/community/releases/70/

Comment: @OV Web Solutions, I do know about VIM, but configuration is a pain.  If i could get PHP native function completion i would install it.  I would appreciate your help configuring and placing my vimrc file to do so in windows.  Also is it possible to mimic notepads++ any-word auto-completion, where it would suggest any work one you typed it once?

Answer (score 1):

Install NetBeans with PHP support. OR if you already have netbeans, you need to install PHP plugin by going to Plugins Manager.

If you want code completion for external libraries like Zend, add them in the Gobal Include Path (available in project properties)

Comment: The PHP plug-in is pre-installed as this is the PHP install of Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently deleting the contents of .netbeans/var/cache/index in your user directory (application data on windows etc) fixed it.